# Sails server: Can not lift in production on AWS server

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, sails.js

On running the production server on the ec2 host, it's not working. It just fails silently.

Interestingly, running it on staging works. And also if I copy the content of production.js to staging.js, I can lift the staging server which has production config.

But using `NODE_ENV=production node app.js` always fails.

I have even checked the permission, it's the same for all production.js and staging.js

```
-rw-r--r-- 1
```

It works on my mac, but somehow on AWS ec2 ubuntu instances, I am facing this issue.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Could you use `NODE_ENV=production node app.js --verbose` to check error messages and include more info, please.

Comment: with sudo it is working but with pm2 it is failing. I just changed production.js to prod.js and its working fine.  Any idea why?

Comment: @JorgeVargas ...

Comment: Define your log level with `sails_log__level=verbose npm start` to check the logs so you can find more details.